# How to express "you are holding your bike and then walk, which makes the bike go with you", do you say "I am carrying / taking / walking my bike"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-request

Say, you are not riding on your bike. Instead, you are holding it with your hands. You, then, walk, which makes the bike go with you.

[image]

do you say "**I am carrying / taking / walking my bike**"?

If we used these terms, then would people think that I were moving the bike without its wheels touching the ground, I might lift the bike up and walked (see the picture)

[image]

Comment: I would say 'I am **wheeling** my bicycle'.

Comment: Or you can also say 'I am **walking** my bicycle'.

Comment: @WeatherVane, so, say, a man is on the stretcher, and we say  "Two nurses were wheeling / walking him into the operating theatre."?

Comment: Careful here, because the natural locomotion of a person is by walking. If you say **walking** him, it will seem as though they are assisting him to walk. If they are carrying the stretcher, they are **carrying** him. If is a wheeled stretcher they are **wheeling** him.

Comment: I might say I am **pushing** my bike.  In the real world, more likely in a context like *The mud was so bad I had to get off and push*

Comment: @WeatherVane, what about a motorbike which is quite heavy, do we say "he is pushing / wheeling / walking the motorbike"

Comment: @WeatherVane, can we say, "he is wheeling his suitcase"? (the suitcase has wheels)